# WCF Services show methods like LoginAsync(...) instead of Login(...)

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

So I made a simple service that allows Registrations and LogIns, so the only methods in my service contract are : Register(string username, string password) and LogIn(string username, string password). When starting the service in the Visual Studio service hosting gizmo I can call my methods properly and everything works well.

My problem is when I try to implement my service in an application. I kept it really simple, one form with fields for username and password for a login. I added a the service by going to Data -> Add New Data Source and gave my address from IIS (the service is hosted in IIS7). Here is a snipped of the would-be implementation code

```
public class LoginServiceClient
{
    static LoginService.LoginClient client = new LoginClient();

    public static bool LogIn(string username, string password)
    {
        string Username = username;
        string HashedPassword = password; // No hash in place yet.

        client.
        return true;//Its *that* easy to get in my system.
    }
}
```

Now the part that isn't working is the line where I started typing "client." expecting to find method names like LogIn and Register instead its LoginAsync and RegisterAsync. Both does not return anything therefore I cannot use them, neither are they offering callback methods.

What did I do wrong ? I can post more code if needed, from the service or details about implementation (as small as it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worry not, you've done nothing wrong. The fact of the matter is that Silverlight requires many operations to be asynchronous; calling a WCF service (or making any sort of network request, for that matter) falls into that category of operations.

You're going to want to look into [consuming asynchronous patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) in the .NET Framework and Silverlight to get used to this new way of doing things. (Oh, and before you ask, Silverlight doesn't support turning these into synchronous operations; you might have to restructure some of your code to work this way.)

Comment: You are right, I guess I'm going to have to make some research in to this way of doing things. I'll read that page on async patterns and see what I can dig up. For this while I'll use the generated file along svcutil until I get to know these pattern better.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you accidentally told svcutil to generate your service proxy as an async implementation.  When you chose Add New Data Source, was there any option for async?  I honestly never use that auto generated crap, I always use svcutil:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx

It looks like you accidentally triggered this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx

Comment: I did some research and I tried invoking svcutil and imported the resultant file into my application and it worked nicely. I would have preferred to use the reference instead of the file but hey if it works.

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed that... per [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896571(v=vs.95).aspx), you can't use proxies generated by SvcUtil in Silverlight; you must use [SLSvcUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197958(v=vs.95).aspx) instead.

Comment: I see, I did not start my application in time to see that. Crashes when calling the proxy, here goes my magic sandcastle... Time for reading I see.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that you were working in silverlight. I don't mess with that haha.